# Disable unused variable warning from Boost graph library within CMake

Tags: c++, boost, cmake, boost-graph

I only want to disable unused variable warnings from BGL, and keep such warnings for my own code. I have read similar answers suggesting include boost as system header, but I don't know how to do that in CMake...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your compiler supports the pragma disable warning #number then you can surround the BGL code with pragma disable ... and pragma enable ...